# How to return auto increment id from objectstore.put() in an IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

How do I return the auto incremented ID after inserting a record into an IndexedDB using objectstore.put()?

Below is my code:

```
idb.indexedDB.addData = function (objectStore, data) {
    var db = idb.indexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction([objectStore], READ_WRITE);
    var store = trans.objectStore(objectStore);
　
　
　
    var request = store.put(data);
    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        //Success, how do I get the auto incremented id?
    };
    request.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log("Error Adding: ", e);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `e.target.result`. Since the API is async, you must use callback to get the return value, as follow:

```
idb.indexedDB.addData = function (objectStore, data, callback) {
    var db = idb.indexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction([objectStore], READ_WRITE);
    var store = trans.objectStore(objectStore);
　    　
    var request = store.put(data);
    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        callback(e.target.result);
    };
    request.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log("Error Adding: ", e);
        callback(undefined);
    };
};
```

Comment: Note that in Chrome in 42.0.2311.135 if you load the IndexedDB results in the inspector and then add a record it does not refresh in the inspector (even clicking off and back on the IndexedDB tab). Refreshing the page or entering and deleting a search key forces a refresh and shows the record.

Comment: This may be off topic, but is it possible to use `add` here instead of `put` here? I'd like to use `add` because of code clarity. My experiment on google chrome suggests that `e.target.result` on `add` indeed returns the generated key. However, this behavior is nowhere to be found on MDN docs, unlike the docs for `put`, which states "success event is fired on the returned request object with the result set to the key for the stored record".

Answer (score 1):

Solved. You can get the incremented id by using `request.result`.