# How to get the (autoincremented) id of an object added to an IndexedDB by objectstore.add()?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm working on a WebExtension and using IndexedDB to store objects. When I store a new object, it will not be already unique. Therefore I use an autoincremented id to make it unique. After its first addition I will do some work, modify/update some properties and therefore have to update the object inside the database. But to update an object, I need to know its ID, which I don't so far.

This is my code to add an object to the database:

```js
const dbName = "MyDb";
const dbVersion = 1;
const storeName = "MyStore";

function addObject(obj) {
    const request = window.indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
    request.onupgradeneeded = event => {
        const db = event.target.result;
        const objectStore = db.createObjectStore(storeName, { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
    }
    request.onsuccess = event => {
        const db = event.target.result;
        const transaction = db.transaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
        const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
        objectStore.add(obj);
        transaction.onerror = event => {
            console.error('Error while adding an object: ', event.target.error.message);
        };
        // How do I get/return the ID of the previously added object?
        transaction.onsuccess = event => {
            console.log(event.target.result);
        };
        transaction.oncomplete = event => {
            console.log(event.target.result);
        };
    }
}

addObject({prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar", prop3: "", prop4: ""});
```

The answers from similar questions - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13492785/11942268) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12502830/11942268) - suggest to query `event.target.result` after a succesful addition, but it returns `undefined` in the above code, although the object has been inserted successfully.

So, is there a way to obtain the ID of the just added object?

Comment: the success event pertaining to the request, not the transaction. there is a difference.

Comment: What if you change `console.log(event.target.result);` to `console.log(event);`? What is inside those events?

Comment: @Josh Thx, that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, I was listening to the wrong event handler. Instead of listening to `onsuccess`/`oncomplete` of the transaction you have to listen to `onsuccess` of the query.

Furthermore, I wrapped everything into a `Promise` to be able to get the id as soon as it is available.

This is the working example:

```js
const dbName = "MyDb";
const dbVersion = 1;
const storeName = "MyStore";

function addObject(obj) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        const request = window.indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
        request.onupgradeneeded = event => {
            const db = event.target.result;
            const objectStore = db.createObjectStore(storeName, { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
        };
        request.onsuccess = event => {
            const db = event.target.result;
            const transaction = db.transaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
            const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);
            const query = objectStore.add(obj);
            transaction.onerror = event => {
                console.error('Error while adding an object: ', event.target.error.message);
            };
            query.onsuccess = event => {
                return resolve(event.target.result); // OR: return resolve(query.result);
            };
        };
    });
}

let id = await addObject({prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar", prop3: "", prop4: ""});
```